# Appium Foreground/Driver Quit

Tags: java, automation, appium

I have an appium code snippet to install and launch an application, issue is that if I use `driver.quit()` to keep appium session running, the app always runs in the background. If `driver.quit()` is not used, appium needs to be restarted each time. Has any one faced this issue by any chance, if so any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you elaborate what exactly are you trying to achieve

Comment: Nothing serious, was running through some basic Appium exercise, figured out that quit might terminate the app activity itself (not entirely sure). Solution needed was to keep the app running in foreground on each run of the code and not just the first 'install & open' run.

Comment: to keep the app running in foreground and not to install and open it on another test run, you can provide the server capabilities mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shall provide you a way to uninstall the application and not let it run in background and then quitting the driver closing all associated windows with :

```
((AppiumDriver) driver).removeApp("<package name>");
driver.quit();
```

Or the way you might be looking to run the app in foreground and not resetting on every test run, could be setting the flag for `reset` as mentioned in the [fullReset and noReset here](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#appium-server-capabilities) and do something like this :

```
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", fullReset);
```